# Scan any Bluetooth Devices on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I just want to get a list of **any Bluetooth Devices around me**, but CoreBluetooth display only Bluetooth Low Energy (4.0.

I don't want to connect to a device, but just display its name.

Is there a solution to do this?

Answer (score 7):

What you want to do is scan for all the `CBPeripheral` in your area. `CBPeripheral` is the class that does the *broadcasting* of any `CBService`(s) that the peripheral may advertise.

To scan for these peripherals you will need an instance of `CBCentralManager`. `CBCentralManager` is the class that does the *scanning* of your peripherals.

To do this you must instantiate your `CBCentralManager`

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: .main)
```

A good idea is before you scan for peripherals to tell your `CBCentralManager` that you only want to discover unique peripherals only once.

```
let options: [String: Any] = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: 
                              NSNumber(value: false)]
```

And when you tell your `CBCentralManager` to scan, don't specify any services of the advertising `CBPeripheral`(s). Instead pass `nil` for this parameter to indicate you want to discover *all* peripherals.

```
centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: options)
```

The above call will begin the actual scanning for the bluetooth devices in the area. You will receive the callback in the [CBCentralManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate) methods to the result of your scan.

---

To get the name of the bluetooth devices, simple look at the name of the `CBPeripheral`(s) that are discovered. You do this through the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` method `didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral`.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("Discovered \(peripheral.name ?? "")")
}
```

Comment: Basically works, except it discovers the same devices over and over again.

Comment: Can it also scan all bluetooth device when the app is in  background? For my usecase i want to scan all available after specific interval

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!_centralManager) {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
        _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:queue options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:@YES}];
        [_centralManager setDelegate:self];
    }

//found BLE
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    //Array add peripheral
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using like this, connect on button click event and use `CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate` Delegate

```
func connectDevice(sender:UIButton){


                if peripheral != nil {
                    manager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
                    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
                }
        }



 func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        } else {
            self.showAlert(Messages().alert , message: "Bluetooth is not on.")
        }
    }



 func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? NSString
        print(device)

        if device?.containsString(BEAN_NAME) == true {
            self.manager.stopScan()
            self.peripheral = peripheral
            self.peripheral.delegate = self
            manager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is  BEAN_NAME here is that any default name or device name